# When training a GAN, should dropout be disabled in discriminator when training is disabled?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm doing a basic GAN implementation in keras. The training is in phases, first training the discriminator alone, then training the generator as part of a combined model (generator plus discriminator) with the training disabled for the discriminator. If the discriminator has dropout in it, it seems to me that it should be disabled when training the generator via the combined model. Is this true?  And if so, how can it be done in keras?  I understand that setting `trainable=false` does not disable dropout.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, dropout should be disabled for generator while training the discriminator or at any testing stage. And good thing is that keras does this by default [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L81).

So looking at your scenario, you can call predict function for generator by using the `trainable` flag and train the discriminator using that as the input.

Hope that answer your question.

Comment: The combined model has the generator feeding the discriminator, but the discriminator is not training (generator is). I think you are saying that having trainable=False for the discriminator will disable it's dropout though?  I can see the code, but I'm vague on whether the trainable flag flows down to the dropout layers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have updated my answer. For ref, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L126